# Speech recognition in vb.net without that annoying recognition window (and about the recognition XML)

Tags: xml, vb.net, window, speech-recognition

1.How to enable speech recognition without that annoying recognition window, and without having to press that button on that window?

2.I need to know how to recognize only the words in the XML that I created (to increase accuracy).
Like:
If I say "red" and that's not in the XML the recognizer will read it like "bread" or something in the XML.

P.S: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recognition engine.

```
Private sr As New Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine()
```

[Bind it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtodefaultaudiodevice.aspx) to an audio device.

[Load grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.loadgrammar) (probably via `Speech.Recognition.Choices`, where choices are read from xml).

[Start recognizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizeasync) and wait for completition (either checking state in a loop or by handling [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechrecognized)).